# Asp.net Core 1.0 TagBuilder Append give Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.BufferedHtmlContent result

Tags: tag-helpers, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to make `<pager>` tag helper and using TagBuilder.InnerHtml.Append in asp.net core 1.0 but the output generates Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.BufferedHtmlContent.

PagerTagHelper class Process method is shown below that creating li tags in main ul and append a tag in each li tag

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    int totalPages, currentPage;
    var url = context.AllAttributes["link-url"];
    output.TagName = "div";
    output.PreContent.SetContent("<ul class=\"link-list\">");
    var items = new StringBuilder();

    for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
    {
        // Creating li TagBuilder
        var li = new TagBuilder("li");

        // Creating a TagBuilder
        TagBuilder a = new TagBuilder("a");
        a.MergeAttribute("href", $"{url}?page={i}");
        a.MergeAttribute("title", $"Click to go to page {i}");
        a.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString());

        if (i == currentPage)
        {
            a.AddCssClass("active");
        }

        li.InnerHtml.Append(a.InnerHtml.ToString());
        items.AppendLine(li.InnerHtml.ToString());
    }

    output.Content.SetContent(items.ToString());
    output.PostContent.SetContent("</ul>");
    output.Attributes.Clear();
    output.Attributes.Add("class", "pager");
}
```

And the result of pager TagHelper output:

```
<ul class="link-list">
    Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.BufferedHtmlContent
    Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.BufferedHtmlContent...     
</ul>
```

Comment: please indent your code properly.

Comment: I have found solution on this page http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/275/custom-taghelpers-in-asp-net-mvc-6

Answer (score 0):

```
var ul = new TagBuilder("ul");
foreach (var item in links)    
{
    var li = new TagBuilder("li");
    var a = new TagBuilder("a");
    a.MergeAttribute("href", item.Attributes["href"].Value);
    a.InnerHtml.Append(item.InnerText);
    li.AddCssClass("test");
    li.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(a);
    ul.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(li);
}
output.Content.SetHtmlContent(ul);
```